# How to get values from registered json output conditionally in ansible

Tags: json, loops, ansible, jinja2

I am trying to parse the json output of yum module, to conditionally get data.
My playbook looks like below:

```
    ---
    - hosts: all
      become: true

      tasks:
      - name: list ggk rpms
        yum:
          list: "{{ item }}"
        register: ggk_njk_info
        ignore_errors: yes
        with_items:
          - ggk_base
          - njk_tt_client

      - debug: msg="{{ item.results }}"
        with_items: "{{ ggk_njk_info.results }}"
        when: item.results
```

The output for the debug task looks like below:

A part of the debug looks like below:

```
     "msg": [
            {
                "arch": "noarch",
                "envra": "0:njk_tt_client-2.36.11-1.noarch",
                "epoch": "0",
                "name": "njk_tt_client",
                "release": "1",
                "repo": "ggk_Software",
                "version": "2.36.11",
                "yumstate": "available"
            },
            {
                "arch": "noarch",
                "envra": "0:njk_tt_client-2.36.11-1.noarch",
                "epoch": "0",
                "name": "njk_tt_client",
                "release": "1",
                "repo": "installed",
                "version": "2.36.11",
                "yumstate": "installed"
            },
            {
                "arch": "noarch",
                "envra": "0:njk_tt_client-2.36.3-1.noarch",
                "epoch": "0",
                "name": "njk_tt_client",
                "release": "1",
                "repo": "ggk_Software",
                "version": "2.36.3",
                "yumstate": "available"
            }
        ]
    }
```

I would like to find the rpm "version" ONLY when its corresponding  "yumstate" is "installed"

In this case i would like to be able to get the version for below:

```
                "repo": "installed",
                "version": "2.36.11",
```

Comment: something like this might help, ```"{{ item.results.msg[0].repo }}"``` and ```"{{ item.results.msg[0]. version }}"```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[json_query](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#json-query-filter) does the job. For example the task below

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ ggk_njk_info.results|
             json_query('[?yumstate==`installed`].{repo: repo,
                                                   version: version}') }}"
```

gives

```
"msg": [
    {
        "repo": "installed", 
        "version": "2.36.11"
    }
]
```

Comment: I was able to get it using with get_version: "[?yumstate =='installed'].version"

Comment: Right. Any [combination of parameters](http://jmespath.org/examples.html#jmespath-examples) is possible. Scalar, list, or dictionary.